# Laravel if no data from select many to many relation

Tags: laravel, if-statement, many-to-many

How to check whether there's data from database or not 
My DB looks like this

[image]

My user Model

```
public function monsters()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Monster')->orderBy('star');
}
```

My Controller

```
public function list_monster_user()
{
    //GET USER LOGIN ID
    $id = Auth::user()->id;

    $monster_user = User::find($id);

    //IF DATA IS NOT EMPTY OR USER HAVE MONSTERS
    if(!is_null($monster_user->monsters))
    {
        return 'yes';
    }

    //IF DATA IS EMPTY OR USER DOESNT HAVE ANY MONSTER
    else
    {
        return 'nope';
    }
}
```

I'm using ajax, so the result will be return to ajax. 
I don't get the return I want. I know something's wrong with my if statement. 
But I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not following naming conventions, you should specify all fields in `belongsToMany` function. Try this:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Monster', 'karakter_has_monster', 'karakter_id', 'monster_id');
```

And to check for results, you could use `count()`. It would be faster.

```
if($monster_user->monsters()->count() > 0) {
    //has monsters
}
```